# validate.js validating arrays

Tags: reactjs, validate.js

I'm using validate.js in react to validate a form.
In parts of the form, fields can be added dynamically. For example like phone numbers.

How do I create validations for each of the fields that are newly created or already exist?
This is as far as I got.

```
phonenumbers: {
 type: 'array'
}
```

Comment: can you iterate over each phone number and validate?
this.phoneNumbers.map((item, key) =>
    validate(item, constraints);
);

Comment: That's a good idea. The rest of the form has an error element which captures the result of the validation. I guess I can append the array errors into this one or create another error element to store these errors. Will try it, thanks.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked, thanks. I also had to take into account deleting/adding rows and updating errors array respectively.

Comment: validate.js has an example on how to do just that https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/dynamic-totals.html

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each phone number and validate.
Something like :

```
this.phoneNumbers.map((item, key) => validate(item, constraints););
```